# Dailymotion API - Search Restriction

Tags: dailymotion-api

I have a problem on video search. With a French IP, everything works well, but with Ireland IP no.

I try :

`https://api.dailymotion.com/user/xm44zy/videos?search=RC%20Lens` on French IP -> 500+ results

`https://api.dailymotion.com/user/xm44zy/videos?search=RC%20Lens` on Ireland IP -> 1 result

Maybe Video access error (DM007 Video geo-restricted by its owner) https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#access-error ?

**No** because `https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x6f8qjq` works well. Not found on search query (with Ireland IP) but I have access to the detail of the video

an idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API will always returns information about a specific video if you request data with its own resource URI (like: https://api.dailymotion.com/video/ID), even if the video is restricted in your country.

However, when using listings (i.e. asking for a video list, or when searching for videos based on search terms), the list will automatically exclude videos which can't be played in your country.

You can know if a video is geoblocked in your country using the "geoblocking" field:
https://developer.dailymotion.com/api/internal#video-geoblocking-field.

In your case, your example is geo-restricted everywhere else France, that's why it won't show in search results (or any listings): `https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x6f8qjq?fields=id,title,geoblocking`

> returns: "geoblocking": [
>       "allow",
>       "fr"
>     ]

This means you can only watch it ( and appears in search results ) in France